# struct from arduino to ctype struct

Tags: python, arduino, ctypes

i am storing Serial data send from an AVR/Arduino in a bytearray.
Since that array stores 2 bytes that are not struct data i need to find a way to "ignore" theese. I found a solution by increasing the pointer by 2 * typelength
and the use of memmove (ignoring interpretation of struct id in my code because its unrelevant). When i print out my struct vars i dont get the results i want,the values are completely different. Using Arduino Nano aka 328p.

```
class BMS_Struct(LittleEndianStructure):
     _fields_ = [("cells", c_uint16 * 13),
                 ("total_voltage", c_uint16),
                 ("current", c_uint16),
                 ("rsense", c_uint16),
                 ("cellreference", c_uint8),
                 ("cellcount", c_uint8),
                 ("bms_mode", c_bool)]

ctype_struct = BMS_Struct()
arduino = serial.Serial()

def receive_struct():
  start = 0x85
  detected_start = False
  message_length = 0
  data_in = 0
  crc = 0
  arduino.baudrate = 57600
  arduino.timeout = 0
  arduino.port = 'COM8'
  try:
      arduino.open()
  except serial.SerialException, e:
    print e

  while True:
    if(arduino.inWaiting() > 1 and detected_start == False):
        data = ord(arduino.read())
        if data == start:
          detected_start = True
        else: print data
    elif(arduino.inWaiting() > 1 and detected_start == True and message_length == 0):
      message_length = ord(arduino.read())
      print "Got message length ", message_length
      data_in = c_uint8 * message_length
      data_in = data_in()
      data_in[0] = message_length
    elif(arduino.inWaiting() >= message_length-1 and detected_start == True and message_length != 0):
      for index in range(message_length-5):
        data_in[index+1] = ord(arduino.read())

      for index in range(4):
        crc |= (ord(arduino.read())<<(index*8) )
      print "CRC arduino = ",hex(crc), format(crc, '032b')
      crc_python = (binascii.crc32(data_in) & 0xffffffff)
      print "CRC pyhton =  ", hex(crc_python),format(crc_python, '032b')


      test = data_in[2:len(data_in)-1]  // returns a list instead of c_ubyte array    
      ptr = cast(data_in, POINTER(c_ubyte))
      ptr = cast(pointer(ptr), POINTER(c_void_p))
      ptr.contents.value += sizeof(ptr._type_)* 2 // increase pointer by 2 * type  
      memmove(pointer(ctype_struct), ptr, len(data_in)-2)
      print ctype_struct.cells[0]
      print ctype_struct.cells[2]
      ctype_struct.cells[0] = 5

      detected_start = False
      message_length = 0
      crc = 0
```

On arduino side

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  bms.cells[1] = 327;
  bms.cellcount = 10;
}   

void loop() {
  write_struct_serial((byte*)&bms, sizeof(bms), BMS_ID); 
  delay(1000);
}

byte write_struct_serial(uint8_t* struct_ptr, uint8_t struct_length, uint8_t struct_id){
  byte data_out[struct_length + 2];  // msg_length1, struct_id1, struct[], crc4 defined as message
  data_out[0] =  2 + struct_length + 4; // Mesage length
  data_out[1] =  struct_id;
  for(byte i=0; i<struct_length; i++){    
    data_out[i+2] = *(struct_ptr+i);
  }

  unsigned long crc = crc_string_byte((byte*)data_out, sizeof data_out);
  Serial.write(start);
  Serial.write(data_out, sizeof data_out);
  Serial.write(crc);
  Serial.write(crc>>8);
  Serial.write(crc>>16);
  Serial.write(crc>>24); 
}
struct BMS
{
  unsigned int cells[13];
  unsigned int bms_total_voltage;
  unsigned int current;  
  unsigned int rsense;
  byte cellreference;  //1.22 for cell type 0/1, for 2/3 0.61
  byte cellcount;
  boolean bms_mode;
};
```

In C i do this by using pointers and memcpy between 2 AVR via I2C, working well.

```
struct BMS bms;
byte* struct_ptr =  ((byte*)&msg_in)+2;     // msg_in byte[]
memcpy(&bms,struct_ptr,struct_length);      //
```

Maybe there is a problem because ctype structs are not equivalently saved in ram like structs on the AVR, maybe i should use Union ?

I didnt find any hint at ctypes doc that point out how the struct is represented in memory (or being compatible to all c-compiled structs), just that it creates c-compatible types. Arduino uses gnu-c compiler and i´m using ver 1.05 maybe i have to check if both compilers have the same version ?
Further investigation resulted in my struct data not being the same all the time, but i´m sending the same over and over again, can this even work the way i want it to ?

**EDIT:**
Seems like the pointer solution did not work, ptr.contents.value += sizeof(ptr.*type*)* 2 seems to increment by 10 and += 2 increments by 2 but the data is still wrong. I found a simple solution that worked !
*FYI:*

```
  test = c_uint8 * (message_length -6)
  test = test()
  for index in range(sizeof(test)):
      test[index] = data_in[index+2]
  memmove(pointer(ctype_struct),pointer(test), len(test))
```

Comment: `struct.Struct` objects aren't structures, they're objects with methods that can read and write binary data from or into buffers. You don't show the definitions of `BMS_Struct` and `bms_struct` in your sample code, but I suspect confusion about this could be the cause your problem.

Comment: From `ctypes` documentation: _copies count bytes from src to dst. dst and src must be integers or ctypes instances that can be converted to pointers._ https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, i want to use the incoming data to save it to my python structs, i thought struct would be the right choice isn´t it ?